# Revit 2016 API "Selection Watcher Using Idling Event"

Tags: revit-api

I'm new to the Revit Api and looking for another way to get a selected element other than using the idling event. All the reading I've done, mainly on thebuidingcoder says that this seems to be the only way. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

That is absolutely not the only way. Selecting an element has nothing whatsoever to do with the Idling event. What utter nonsense!

You can pick an element interactively using the Selection.PickObject method.

You can also retrieve the elements pre-selected before launching the command from the Selection.GetElementIds method.

If you are new to the Revit API, the first thing you should do is work through the getting started material, especially the the DevTV and My First Revit Plugin tutorials.

That answers this question of yours immediately, and many more besides:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2

Comment: Indeed. I can see three ways each with its own drawbacks.1-) use the idling event. Not very efficient 2-) use an external command. This seems the only way to get to the Selection.PickObject which means the user has to first select a command from the ribbon bar. 3-) use the ribbon bar work around which will only give me the first three elements. I'm looking for a strait forward way of getting the selection without the user first having to click on a button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do something when the selection *changes*, you might want to check out the following blog post by Jeremy Tammik: [Element Selection Changed Event](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/03/element-selection-changed-event.html).

The basic idea is to subscribe to an event as opposed to polling (the `IdleEvent` method you mentioned or using a timer). Since the Revit API doesn't actually have such an event, a clever guy - let's call him Vilo - came up with the idea to subscribe to the `PanelEvent` of the *Modify* panel. This is ingenious! Read the blog post for more information (and sample code!) on how to do this!!

Comment: Thanx Daren. That post got me started. I'm not keen on the work around as it will only give me the first 3 selections (according to the post) however it may be the only alternative to not having the user first click on a button before I can get the selection.